# Parseval identity to compute $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^2dx$

Tags: functional-analysis

The Parseval identity in Hilbert space $H$ is

> If $h \in H$, $\lVert h\rVert = \sum \{|<h,e>|^2:e \in S\}  $  then when $S$ is a basis for $H$

How to use this to compute

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2dx$$

Comment: You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) version of the identity more helpful.

Comment: The sum form of Parseval is for Fourier transforms on the circle. You need to use the integral form of Parseval, known as Plancherel, for an integral over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use _Parseval_ here? It's a natural application of the _Plancherel_ theorem

Answer (score 3):

Note that$$\int_{-1}^1\frac12e^{ikx}dk=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}=\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$So$$\int_{\Bbb R}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2dx=2\pi\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac12\right)^2dk=\pi.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Plancherel and the Fourier Transform on the Line**

Compute the Fourier transform of $\pi\left[-\frac1{2\pi}\le x\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\pi\left[-\frac1{2\pi}\le x\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{e^{-i\xi}-e^{i\xi}}{-2i\xi}\\
&=\frac{\sin\left(\xi\right)}{\xi}
\end{align}
$$
Apply Plancherel:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi}\right)^2\mathrm{d}\xi
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\pi^2\left[-\frac1{2\pi}\le x\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi^2\cdot\frac1\pi\\[6pt]
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$
Note that $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

---

**Fourier Series on the Circle and Riemann Sums**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2kx)}{k}
&=\frac{\log\left(1-e^{-2ix}\right)-\log\left(1-e^{2ix}\right)}{2i}\tag1\\
&=\frac{i\pi-2ix}{2i}\tag2\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi-2x}2\tag3\\[3pt]
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{k^2}
&=\frac{\pi x-x^2}2\tag4\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{(kx)^2}x
&=\frac{\pi-x}2\tag5\\
\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^2\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac\pi2\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: power series for $\log(1-x)$
$(2)$: $\log(-e^{-2ix})=i\pi-2ix$
$(3)$: simplify
$(4)$: integrate with respect to $x$
$(5)$: divide by $x$
$(6)$: Riemann Sum as $x\to0$
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ the total variation of $\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^2$ is less than $\frac43$ on $[0,\infty)$
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ so the Riemann Sum of the improper integral converges properly